# Unique extension of the absolute value

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, absolute-value

Let $(K,u)$ be a complete valued field, $u$ be its *discrete* absolute value (corresponds to a discrete valuation on $K$), then:

> ($\ast)$ *Let $E/K$ is a finite separable field extension, then the absolute value $w$ of $E$ which extends $u$ is unique.*

In the book *Algebraic Number Theory* by *Fröhlich, A., and Taylor, M.J.*, it first proves the above property, then gives an alternate proof as follows:

> *Let $\mathfrak o$ denotes the valuation ring in $K$ associates with $u$, $\mathfrak o_E$ the integral closure of $\mathfrak o$ in $E$,
>
>   then in order to prove ($\ast$), it suffices to show that $\mathfrak o_E$ has the unique prime ideal $\mathfrak B$ above $\mathfrak o$.*
>
> ($\mathfrak B$ is above $\mathfrak o$ means $\mathfrak B \cap \mathfrak o=\mathfrak p$ is an unique prime ideal in $\mathfrak o$.)

My question is, how the uniqueness of $\mathfrak B$ implies the uniqueness of extension $w$, why it suffices?

I know there exists a absolute value $w'$ of $E$ extends $u$ which gives $\mathfrak {B} =\{  x; w'(x)<1  \}$, but this only works for such specific $w'$, for an arbitrary extension $w$, not even being discrete, I am not sure how it gives a prime ideal in $\mathfrak o_E$ to obtain the uniquemess.

Comment: Localize and use the fact that DVRs are maximal amongst domination.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I am not sure what to localise and how that solve my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In non-archimedean case, absolute value corresponds to prime ideals.