# Krasner's lemma, condition for the ground field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

On the Wikipedia and in some other sources (e.g. planetmath), Krasner's lemma is stated like this :
Given $K$ complete non-archimedean field, let $\overline{K}$ be its algebraic closure, let $\alpha ,\beta\in\overline{K}$ such that $$|\alpha -\beta|<|\alpha -\alpha _i|$$ for all conjugates $\alpha _i$ of $\alpha$. Then $K(\alpha)\subset K(\beta)$.

I don't understand why $K$ is allowed to be general complete field and not a local field. Namely, if $K$ is a local field, then there exists a unique extension of the absolute value of $K$ to $L$, for every finite extension $L$ of $K$. But, I think that this is not the case for $K$ general complete field (at least in the proof I have seen, existence relies on its local compactness).

Comment: I think you also need to assume that $K$ is of characteristic zero. Then it is true that any finite extension has a unique extensions of absolute value. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402470/unique-extension-of-the-absolute-value). I am not sure if this was your question

Comment: OK, now I think I understand , thanks. So if we are given a complete field then on any separable extension there exists a unique extension of absolute value, however the proof I looked deals only with the local fields, I didn't know it holds in full generality. Yes, since I wrote algebraic closure instead of separable, indeed char $K$ has to be 0.

Comment: Just because a particular *proof* uses a hypothesis does not make that hypothesis essential.  For example, in Koblitz's book on $p$-adic analysis and zeta-functions he only proves uniqueness of the extension of an absolute value from a complete valued field to each finite extension of it when the base field is locally compact, such as $\mathbf Q_p$.  But with other techniques you can prove the same uniqueness for arbitrary complete valued fields as base field: no need for local compactness (or for characteristic $0$).   See Theorem 3.2 (p. 37) of http://math.uga.edu/~pete/8410FULL.pdf.